# XRAY is not scanning "Artifactory block un-scanned image"

Tags: docker, artifactory, pypi

Xray not scanning remote cache artifacts

Step to produce

1 - After check option in Artifactory ( Block Un-scanned Artifact with XRAY ).

2 - docker pull docker.artifactory/tensorflow/tensorflow/nightly-py3

3 - only manifest.json for tensorflow/nightly-py3 is downloaded into artifactory docker-remote-cache (same outcome for other repositoies such as Pypi )

4 - Xray EVENT log complains "error while downloading from ........manifest.json

5 - Check Xray indexed repositories, Index Status does not update, and image never get scanned.

What I want to see is.

1. User pull through Artifactory remote
2. Xray realtime scan
3. Artifactory allow/deny download

Is there some process i didnt setup XRAY correctly?

Comment: Hi Devric, as you are evaluating/customer of Xray, you are entitled to official support from JFrog Support at support@jfrog.com. I would recommend that you address them directly.

Comment: @Ariel thanks, already got in touch with Mari on this, Also i've send an email out to services and markb, for requesting a demo session, but havent got a response yet, are you able to assist in contact? I need some Technical assistance as I'll be doing a XRAY POC(Proof Of Concept) to a client ( who already have Artifactory Licence ). The POC will help the client to determine if they willing to Adopt XRAY to the project.

Comment: Hi Devric, JFrog Support team will handle your inquiry. There is no specific contact there but it's a team that answers support cases.